# Is it possible to build Post request from the stream in Spray?

Tags: scala, spray

I wonder if it is possible to use spray to build a response based on the stream, not the array of bytes?

I would like to get a file from specific URL—using `Source.fromURL`—and post it as `octet-stream` to the specific URL (e.g. get the file from Nexus and deploy it to Tomcat).

`HttpEntity`'s buffer method is `Array[Byte]`, so I can read entire file into memory and build a `POST` request, and it should work just fine for smaller files, though it would consume enormous amounts of memory in case of huge files.

Comment: Two recent changes will improve the situation in this regard. 1) The buffer in HttpEntity is gone and was replaced by HttpData which can now represent Array[Byte] in combination with bytes directly from files (less important). 2) We've introduced auto-chunking which means you get access to incoming data as chunks as it comes in. So, what you need is a recent nightly of spray and make yourself acquainted with the message flow for chunked requests/responses. See http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-can/http-server/#chunked-requests

Comment: Thanks, it looks fine. Is there any chance that in addition to loading data from file it will also support scala.io.Source or any stream readers?

Comment: spray-routing already supports marshalling of streams (scala.Stream) out of the box (see http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-httpx/marshalling and the according sources) and will send out http chunks in that case.